# UIButtonClass addTarget new View Issue

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have created a Custom UI Button class and I'm trying to add specific targets to these buttons in my UIViewController Class as I've learned I cannot do that. Here is what I have so far:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton{
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setConfig()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setConfig()
    }
    func setConfig(){
        backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "SpecialGreen")
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        layer.zPosition = 2
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "PingFangSC-Semibold", size: 15)
    }
    func touchIn(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction,.curveEaseIn], animations: {
            self.transform = .init(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    func touchOut(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction,.curveEaseOut], animations: {
            self.transform = .identity
        }, completion: nil)
        let impactFeedbackgenerator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .rigid)
        impactFeedbackgenerator.prepare()
        impactFeedbackgenerator.impactOccurred()
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        touchIn()
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        touchOut()
        
    }
    
}
```

In my main class I create buttons like this:

```
        let settingsbtn = CustomButton()
        settingsbtn.backgroundColor = .clear
        settingsbtn.layer.borderWidth = 0
        settingsbtn.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.size.width - 60, y: 60, width: 50, height: 50)
        settingsbtn.tintColor = UIColor.gray
        settingsbtn.setImage(settingsImage, for: .normal)
        settingsbtn.layer.zPosition = 2
        settingsbtn.tag = 5
        self.view.addSubview(settingsbtn)
```

How would I go about targeting a new view controller with the custom button. I have tried many ways and I can't seem to get it. I would create it in the UIButton Class as a target but the class does not recognize anything with views. Thank you!

To add some clarity, I'm looking to press the button and present a different view controller.

Comment: I don't quit understand what you want to achieve tbh

Comment: I want to click the button and go to a different view controller

Comment: Why are you overwriting a button's touch handling? It already has great touch handling. That's what it is to be a button...

Comment: Because I'm looking for this specific animation, I can't do this animation in the view controller. @matt

Comment: I don't see why you can't do it with the normal UIControl touch events.

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Maybe look into chaning the animation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384854/custom-segue-transition-animation instead of how the viewChange is called

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options...

First, instead of overriding the `touch` events, override `isHighlighted` and perform the animation there.
Then, you can use normal `.addTarget(...)` and trigger the haptic feedback in your `touchUpInside` selector func.

Here's a complete example:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setConfig()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setConfig()
    }
    func setConfig(){
        backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "SpecialGreen")
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        layer.zPosition = 2
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "PingFangSC-Semibold", size: 15)
    }
    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if isHighlighted {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction,.curveEaseIn], animations: {
                    self.transform = .init(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
                }, completion: nil)
            } else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction,.curveEaseOut], animations: {
                    self.transform = .identity
                }, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the example view controller:

```
class CustViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let settingsbtn = CustomButton()
        settingsbtn.backgroundColor = .clear
        settingsbtn.layer.borderWidth = 0
        settingsbtn.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.size.width - 60, y: 60, width: 50, height: 50)
        settingsbtn.tintColor = UIColor.gray
        if let settingsImage = UIImage(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3") {
            settingsbtn.setImage(settingsImage, for: .normal)
        }
        settingsbtn.layer.zPosition = 2
        settingsbtn.tag = 5
        self.view.addSubview(settingsbtn)
        
        settingsbtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.settingsButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func settingsButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {
        print("Settings Button Tapped")
        
        // haptic feedback
        let impactFeedbackgenerator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .rigid)
        impactFeedbackgenerator.prepare()
        impactFeedbackgenerator.impactOccurred()

        // do something, such as
        let vc = SomeViewController()
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

If you **really** want to put the haptic feedback inside your custom button, you can send the `touchUpInside` event inside `touchesEnded`. You *probably* only want to trigger the haptic feedback and "tap" event if the touch ended inside the button.

Here's a complete example of taking that approach:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setConfig()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setConfig()
    }
    func setConfig(){
        backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "SpecialGreen")
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        layer.zPosition = 2
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "PingFangSC-Semibold", size: 15)
    }
    func touchIn(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction,.curveEaseIn], animations: {
            self.transform = .init(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    func touchOut(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction,.curveEaseOut], animations: {
            self.transform = .identity
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        touchIn()
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        touchOut()
        // only trigger haptic feedback and touchUpInside event
        //  if touches ended inside self
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let touchpoint:CGPoint = touch.location(in: self)
            if bounds.contains(touchpoint) {
                let impactFeedbackgenerator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .rigid)
                impactFeedbackgenerator.prepare()
                impactFeedbackgenerator.impactOccurred()
                self.sendActions(for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and the (almost identical) example view controller:

```
class CustViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let settingsbtn = CustomButton()
        settingsbtn.backgroundColor = .clear
        settingsbtn.layer.borderWidth = 0
        settingsbtn.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.size.width - 60, y: 60, width: 50, height: 50)
        settingsbtn.tintColor = UIColor.gray
        if let settingsImage = UIImage(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3") {
            settingsbtn.setImage(settingsImage, for: .normal)
        }
        settingsbtn.layer.zPosition = 2
        settingsbtn.tag = 5
        self.view.addSubview(settingsbtn)
        
        settingsbtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.settingsButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        
    }
    
    @objc func settingsButtonTapped() -> Void {
        print("Settings Button Tapped")
        // do something, such as
        let vc = SomeViewController()
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```